# Build generates BuildConfig.java with wrong package name for androidTest with newer gradle versions

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I have an app with associated Espresso tests.
It currently builds and runs properly with the following versions of Gradle (values I see in Android Studio, when I open File -> Project Structure)

```
Android Gradle Plugin Version: 7.1.2
Gradle Version: 7.2
```

My gradle build files define some build config fields definitions. My test code has some references to fields in the BuildConfig class generated for debug. As I said earlier, everything works fine. When I build the debug flavor of the application's APK and the test APK, a BuildConfig.java file is generated under app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/xyz/abc/ (the class' package is com.xyz.abc). It contains all the fields I had declared for the debug flavor of my app in my gradle files.  Another BuildConfig.java file is generated under app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/androidTest/debug/com/xyz/abc/test/BuildConfig.javand this time the class is in package com.xyz.abc.test. It only contains the fields DEBUG, APPLICATION_ID, and BUILD_TYPE.

In my test code as long as I import com.xyz.abc.BuildConfig, I am able to reference any field from the app's debug BuildConfig class.

I am trying to upgrade to more recent versions of Gradle and the plugin so I changed my settings to this

```
Android Gradle Plugin Version: 7.3.0-alpha04
Gradle Version: 7.4
```

Then I rebuilt my app and my test APKs, like this

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleDebug assembleDebugAndroidTest
```

The test APK failed to build because every time I was using a BuildConfig field in the test code, the compiler spit out an undefined reference error.

When I looked at the BuildConfig.java files, I found out that the one generated for the test APK was under app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/androidTest/debug/com/xyz/abc/ and this time, as the path indicates, the package is com.xyz.abc, and not com.xyz.abc.**test**

So of course, every time I import com.xyz.abc.BuildConfig in the test code, it's that class that gets referenced, not the one from the app. Since it only contains the fields DEBUG, APPLICATION_ID, and BUILD_TYPE, any reference to a field from the app's BuildConfig class cannot be resolved.

I am not sure when this behavior started but everything builds fine with

```
Android Gradle Plugin Version: 7.3.0-alpha01
Gradle Version: 7.3.3
```

The issue is still there in 7.3.0-alpha07 (latest version of the plugin that I know of)

Is this a bug? Has some behavior changed?

Answer (score 1):

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig=false
    }
}
```

Set it to false when android-test, and set it to true when other situation.